# jQuery - How to show Loading.gif when clicking Submit Button

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form which allows us to enter data and upload file. When I click the submit button, I wish to show a loading.gif file which allows people to know that the form is processing. The following is the DIV which I hid

```
<div class="formprocessgif" style="display:none;"><img src="images/spiffygif_50x50.gif" align="center"> We are processing your submssion. Please wait...</div>
```

The problem is, I'm not sure where to show this script when we click "Submit". I am using the Validation Plugin for the form, and so I'm not too sure whether I should put it under the ***submitHandler*** in the validation script, or under a separate event for the Submit Button.

**Under the Validation Plugin:**

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(".formprocess.gif").show();  
    $(form).submit();
}
```

**Under an event by itself**

```
$("#papersubmitform").submit(function(event) {
    $(".formprocess.gif").show();  
    $(form).submit();       
});
```

Both doesn't work, unfortunately.. is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is wrong remove the `.` before `gif` like,

```
$(".formprocessgif").show();
```

Your code should be,

```
$("#papersubmitform").submit(function(event) {
    $(".formprocessgif").show();
    // ------------^ remove dot from here
    $(form).submit();       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="formprocessgif"><img src="formprocess.gif"></div>
```

ajax --->

```
$("#papersubmitform").submit(function(event) {
        $("#formprocessgif").show(slow);  // 



    $.ajax({
                   url: 'mail.php',    // your post url
                    type: 'post',
                 data: $('#papersubmitform').serialize(),
                 success: function(response)
                 {
                    // your Action After submit
                }            
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML

```
<div class="formprocessgif"><img src="images/spiffygif_50x50.gif" align="center"> We are processing your submssion. Please wait...</div>
```

The CSS

```
.formprocessgif {
     display: none;
}
```

The JQuery

```
$(form).submit(function() {
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "action.php", //Your URL
           data: $(form).serialize(), //post form data to your url
           success: function() {
                //your action after submit success
           }
     });

     //ajax request start. here we change the display on your class from "none" to "block"
     $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
           $(".formprocessgif").css("display","block");
     });

     //when ajax complete, we change back display to "none" to hidden loading image
     $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
           $(".formprocessgif").css("display","none");
     });

});
```